# How do I call a list from the shiny server in the shiny UI?

Tags: r, shiny

**Situation**: In the server environment I define a list. I want to call this list in the UI-environment.

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
    selectizeInput(
      'chooser', 'Choose an Item', choices = mylist, multiple = TRUE  
    )
)

server=function(input,output){
 mylist=c("Fork", "Tree", "Truck", "Spoon", "Rocket")

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. I get:

```
Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'mylist' not found
```

**Question**: What do I need to change the code to to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mylist)` in the server as follows:

```
library(shiny)

ui=fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(
    'chooser', 'Choose an Item', choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE  
  )
)

server=function(input,output, session){
  mylist=c("Fork", "Tree", "Truck", "Spoon", "Rocket")

  updateSelectizeInput(session, "chooser", choices = mylist)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```